# does "are you still riding that old car" sound ok?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

If I want to joke about my friend's old car, is the sentence correct?

```
are you still riding that old car?
```

Comment: It’s obviously much better to say nothing if you want to stay friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still riding that old car?

If you travel as a passenger in a car, you can say that you ride a car (in AmE) or ride in a car (both in AmE and BrE).  So there's nothing wrong with the sentence if used in this sense.

If you operate a car and control its movement and direction, you say that you drive a car. If used in this sense, the correct sentence is:

Are you still driving that old car?

Answer (score 1):

Khan’s answer is excellent.

Here I offer another good answer, using a selection of words more like your original.

*Are you still riding around in that old car?*